# AWS Lambda No Such Key Error when calling S3 PutObj Test Event

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I've referenced below snippet of code from github and after series of lambda test events (Hello World, S3PutObj, S3Deleteobj), I still experience the below error saying "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation" Even though I've created the "HappyFace.jpg" file and Zipped it and upload to the bucket. Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated. My goal is to have a Python Lambda script to unzip s3 buckets.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import urllib
import zipfile
import boto3
import io


print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'cwlogstestbucket'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']
    ['key'].encode('utf8'))

    try:
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        putObjects = []
        with io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read()) as tf:
        # rewind the file
        tf.seek(0)

        # Read the file as a zipfile and process the members
        with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
            for file in zipf.infolist():
                fileName = file.filename
                putFile = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=fileName, 
                Body=zipf.read(file))
                putObjects.append(putFile)
                print(putFile)


    # Delete zip file after unzip
    if len(putObjects) > 0:
        deletedObj = s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print('deleted file:')
        print(deletedObj)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they 
              exist and your bucket is in the same region as this 
              function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e


"Here is the Error Message"


 "START RequestId: 83e72961-dc48-11e7-be00-b580169f8a7f Version: 
 $LATEST
 An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: 
 The specified key does not exist.
 Error getting object HappyFace.jpg from bucket cwlogstestbucket. 
 Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this 
 function.
 An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: 
 The specified key does not exist.: NoSuchKey
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 43, in lambda_handler
 raise e
 NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject 
 operation: The specified key does not exist."



 "Here is the test event configuration"

    {
    "Records": [
    {
     "eventVersion": "2.0",
     "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
     "requestParameters": {
     "sourceIPAddress": "0.0.0.0"
    },
     "s3": {
      "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
      "object": {
        "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
      "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
      "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
      "size": 1024
    },
    "bucket": {
      "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::cwlogstestbucket",
      "name": "sourcebucket",
      "ownerIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      }
     },
      "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
     },
      "responseElements": {
       "x-amz-id-2": 
  "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
    "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
    },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
      "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
    },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
   }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: What does your event look like?

Comment: smcstewart, please look at the edit above. That's the S3PutObj test event that I used.

Comment: Were you repeatedly creating and deleting the same object while testing?

Comment: That's the test event from the Lambda console. What is the _actual_ event you are trying to use? You will probably want to customise the test event to match your bucket and object key. This error is as it says, "The bucket you are using does not have the object with the key name you're using". Create a bucket, upload a file, configure the Lambda test event to match your bucket and filename and then test it again.

Comment: michael-sqlbot, no, there are already stuffs in the bucket and I've even test it for both when stuffs already there and also upload new stuffs, but I did not delete them while testing.

Comment: smcstewart, I've tried your solution, I've even modified my test event in Lambda to match everything in the bucket. I'm still getting ""errorType": "NoSuchKey",
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist."

Comment: I was able to get object from S3 using below code :  
`import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'cwlogstestbucket' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'HappyFace.jpg' # replace with your object key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'HappyFace.jpg')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise`  
Can you print the key before you try to get object. It seems the key that gets generated doesn't exist.

Comment: @KiranMore, I've used your method as well, it did not help with the error. I've tweaked the test event a bit to make it shorter. {
  "Records": [
    {
      "s3": {
        "object": {
          "key": "000000.gz"
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::cwlogstestbucket",
          "name": "cwlogstestbucket"
        }
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I still get this Error                                File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 44, in lambda_handler
    raise e
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.

Comment: @KiranMore, key could not printed before object as you can see from the lambda test event. I've tried to print, but gave me a totally different reason of error.